# Python Pandas giving me SettingWithCopyWarning when I attempt to map a particular DataFrame column - how to fix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have some code that needs to replace two columns of a pandas DataFrame with the index of each value as they appear in a unique list of those values. For example:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
A, 1, 2, 3
A, 1, 2, 3
B, 1, 2, 3
```

Should end up in the data frame as:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
0, 1, 2, 3
0, 1, 2, 3
1, 1, 2, 3
```

since A is element 0 in the list of unique col1 values, and B is element number 1.

What I did is:

```
unique_vals = df['col1'].unique()

# create a map to speed up looking indexes when we map the dataframe column
unique_vals.sort()
unique_vals_map = {}
for i in range(len(unique_vals)):
    unique_vals_map[unique_vals[i]] = i

df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda r: unique_vals_map[r])
```

However that last line gives me:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I saw other SO answers about this, but I am not sure how to fix it in my particular case. I'm experienced with numpy but I'm new to pandas, any help is greatly appreciated!

Is there a better way to perform this mapping?

Comment: I don't think that solves anything but why `df['col']` and not `df['col1']`? That's not consistent with the required output.

Comment: And importantly, what does `df` look like in the end? Is there an actual problem or just a spurious warning?

Comment: Another tangential suggestion: `df['col1'].map(unique_vals_map)` works too and is shorter than `apply`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the warning in Pandas 1.4.3. What version are you using?

Comment: @Joooeey ops, that was a typo - I was creating a minimal version of my actual code. The pandas version I am in is 2.0.1. The result is correct, but this is very annoying warning as it shows in many sections of my actual code and pollutes the output. I'd like to address whatever is causing it, but it's not clear to me how to fix it.

Comment: Pandas' issue tracker looks like it's full of false positives and many have been there for years. So perhaps it's fine to use the warnings library to suppress the warning. I absolutely can't see anything that would create a copy there.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I will look into the warnings library. Should I close this question? Your info was useful to me, if you want to post an answer I can accept too.

Comment: It's best practice to post an answer once you found it. Unless we have a duplicate somewhere. This is a common issue I've experienced many times.

Comment: Also, there's a newer version of Pandas. Maybe that fixes the warning.

Comment: Interestingly, I can't reproduce with Pandas 2.0.1 either. That's on Python 3.10.11. Are you sure you can reproduce the error with the code above in a new interpreter?

Comment: Here's the generic duplicate target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas It would be interesting what went wrong in this particular case, though!

Comment: @Joooeey I agree, it is a bit of a mystery.. for now I just silenced the warnings and everything seems to be fine....

Comment: Can you post the code you used for creating `df` in the first place?